# How to enable SCIM2 on WSO2 API Manager 3.2.0

Tags: wso2, scim2

After some help that users gave me here I'm having troubles with understanding how to actually use SCIM2 with WSO2 API Manager 3.2.0

I've installed wso2am via docker, and looking inside its folder I see a lot of configuration files regarding scim2, which have all been enabled. But I can't seem to find the actual scim2 servlet.

So I've also installed in another container wso2 Identity Server (5.10), which constains scim2 server and the APIs seem to work, so I decided to create a shared store between Identity Server and API Manager to create users through IS' Scim2 APIs and use those users with the API Manager.

So wso2am is installed on `<ip>:9443` and wso2is on `<ip>:9444`

I've successfully configured a shared user store from IS carbon admin panel, and I can see all the users in the API Manager database.

[image]

But when I try to call the scim2 api on identity server to create a new user for the REMOTE (Api Manager) database, it says:

```
{
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:Error"
    ],
    "detail": "Cannot add user through scim to user store . SCIM is not enabled for user store REMOTE",
    "status": "500"
}
```

Even though in wso2 Api manager configuration files SCIM is enabled.

How can I make this work? Do I need to actually install scim inside the wso2 api manager container? (is there any reference about this?)

Or do I need to configure the identity server as an external key manager?

My only aim is to create new users using scim2 apis for the wso2  api manager.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. If anybody will be interested in the future, I just copied from wso2is folder `scim2.war` and `org.wso2.carbon.identity.provisioning.connector.scim-5.2.1.jar` and pasted them to the same paths but inside the wso2am folder.
Everything works as a charm.

Comment: It's great. Just one question, if you have wso2is in your architecture, why don't you call SCIM API from wso2is instead? Because for me, wso2am is designed for API Gateway not the user management.